# Typing game made in python (timer, multithreading, def(), etc

Tags: python, multithreading, input, timer

```
import random
from threading import Timer

class color:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'

score = 0

list = ("Toothpaste", "Seashell", "Binder", "Computer", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Turing", "Python", "Circuit")
list2 = ("Mathematics", "Onomatopoeia", "Obnoxious", "Archiving", "Licencing")

endgame = 0

def printbob():
    print("you lose bro")
    endgame = 1

def boys():
    points = 0
    while(score >= 0):
        timeout = 3
        timer = Timer(timeout, printbob)
        timer.start()
        if(points < 5):
            cs = random.choice(list)
        else:
            cs = random.choice(list2)
        print("Type this sentence:", color.GREEN + cs + color.END)
        user = "You have %d seconds to choose the correct answer...\n" % timeout
        answer = input(user)
        timer.cancel()
        if (answer == cs) and (endgame == 0):
            print("Nice")
            points += 1
        else:
            print("Bye")
            exit()
boys()
```

This is a program that prints an chosen word from a list, and requires the user to print the exact same word within the constrained time. However, the issue is that if no input is given, the code does not exit since it is waiting for an input.

In short, how can I adjust my code so that the program exits when no input is given.

Thanks,
Robert Daniro

Comment: Edit: Someone just commented and I replied to him , but he deleted his comment or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special keyword input like QUIT or EXIT to exit the program or you can set up an upper limit for the wait time. If the time exceed some value you quit the program with a message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but is there no way of doing this automatically?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not enter any sentence? You can check if len(answer)==0 and then quit.

Comment: Yes, but also lets say the word is "Hello"

And the user types "Hel" so not word exactly, but its more then 0 letters. 

You could say `if(len(cs) != len(answer)):
                  exit`

But that also doesn't work because if the word is "Phone" and the player types "Phoen" which is the same length but the wrong word and the time runs up, it wouldn't exit.